# Bolding in Japanese text has finally been fixed!

Tags: discussion

Bold markup finally works with Japanese!  See this announcement on Meta.StackExchange:

[Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)

Until now, we've been working around this problem by using `<strong>` and `<b>` because the normal markup for bolding, `**`, didn't work without spaces between words.  But now it does:

> 文字を**太字**にする

So we can finally use `**` here on Japanese.SE!  Yippee!

Comment: Previous posts about problems with bolding: [120](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/120/1478) - [532](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/532/1478) - [1091](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1091/1478) - all of these problems have been fixed!

Comment: Woohoo!  Glad it's working.

Comment: That said, it's still hard to notice the bold in the middle of a lot of kana.  Kind of wish we could just turn the text blue to highlight it or something.

Comment: @Troyen It's also possible to use emphasis dots: 文字を[強調]{﹅・﹅}する

Comment: @Troyen We can also use overlines and underlines: 文字を[強調]{HH}する・文字を[強調]{LL}する

Comment: That is pure evil. Pure evil genius.

Comment: The underline thing looks best.  How'd you do that?

Comment: @Troyen http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1294#1294