# Should we use quotes for inline Japanese words or phrases?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

Longer passages should [use block quotes](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1296#1296). This is about when you need to use Japanese words or phrases such as 日本語 within an English paragraph.

Should we use quotes for Kanji and Hiragana/Katakana? I noticed that some members prefer quotes, while others do not. An example:

```
1. What is the difference between 「新{しん}規{き}」 and 「新{あたら}しい」?
2. What is the difference between 新{しん}規{き} and 新{あたら}しい?
```

I think the first example is better, and the sentence looks grammatically correct this way.

We can use 「quotes」 or "quotes" or `backticks` etc. to mark that we're only [mentioning a Japanese word or phrase instead of using it](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1296#1296). Backticks have already been suggested [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1296#1296), but with no votes.

Maybe it would be better to create some rule/standard here, so all members would follow them?

Comment: You could post your opinion (using `「」`) as an answer as well, so that the voting may begin.

Comment: @blutorange Your answer is very good indeed. I will try to use such format for a while as experiment.

Comment: This is just my opinion, I think we should wait until other people had a chance to vote etc ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Unless there's a special need, do not mark it at all.

First of all, should we mark it all? Most importantly, a text should be easy to read. There's no need to add superfluous noise or punctuation if there's no practical chance of confusion.

- 漢字 and かな already stand out in an otherwise English text.
- A paragraph in English almost never actually *uses* a Japanese word, so there won't be any 誤解.
- It's also easier to type.

It's a good idea to mark English text because it doesn't stand out:

> [image]

---

Why not use...

- Japanese 「quotes」: These look a bit strange because that's applying Japanese typography to an English text. Would be like ending with a Japanese period。
- English "quotes": These on the other hand look rather strange with Japanese as well. Combining Japanese+English isn't easy.
- `backticks`:  looks alright for one or two words, but it can get distracting quickly, see below.
- **bold**: Bad **typesetting** practice. Should be **preserved** for **emphasis**.
- *italic*: Good for phonetic transcriptions such as *romaji*, but looks ugly with Japanese: *凸凹*.

> [image]

---

In "The Handbook of Japanese Linguistics", edited by *Natsuko Tsujimura*, this style is being used as well:

[image]

English words that are mentioned get marked, the Japanese script is not marked.

Comment: And now that I think about, `backticks` should be used sparingly for English words as well, or it can get distracting rather quickly too. Often, "quotes" are sufficient; and imo, well-written plain text with paragraphs is easy to read.

Comment: 日本人は深く考えずに[何らかの引用符を使ってしまいそう](https://ja-jp.facebook.com/wordsmythlab/posts/495348977176886)。英語だと違う、と最近知りました。気をつけます。

Comment: @naruto 外見より質とも言えるし、これはあえて投稿したポストを編集したらどうすべきか、何が一番いいかという質問についての意気投合のようなものです。気にしすぎない程度でよろしいかと。

Comment: Now I think this approach is very good and should be used - "English words that are mentioned get marked, the Japanese script is not marked." - as mentioned by @blutorange.