# How to format citations from Japanese texts (author, title, &c.)

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, formatting

**I'll post a few suggestions so that you can vote. Feel free to add your own suggestion.**

---

I've been thinking it would be nice to have establish some guideline how we should format quotations from Japanese, especially but not limited to books/papers.

As always, this shouldn't be a rule but a guideline or recommendation. Peole can do what they want. But if you don't know what to do; or if editing a post for other reasons, it's nice to have  default or guideline.

We don't need academic standards here and this is not about if or what details (author, title, year, publisher &c.) you should give, but how to format it if you choose to do so.

The formatting guide has got [a section on quoting Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1295#1295), but it only mentions that block quotes `>` should be preferred.

Below you can find a few suggestions for voting. Or add your own suggestions if you don't like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Dash and `『』` marks. Author first.

> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。
>
> どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。
>
> ――夏目漱石(1905) 『吾輩は猫である 夏目漱石』

Answer (score 0):

Dot and parentheses. Author first.

> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。
>
> どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。
>
> (夏目漱石, 1905. 吾輩は猫である)

Answer (score 0):

English style. Use `by`. Title first.

> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。
>
> どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。
>
> 吾輩は猫である by 夏目漱石, published 1905

Answer (score 0):

Book style, at the beginning. Title first. Bolded.

> **吾輩は猫である**
>
> **夏目漱石 (1905)**
>
> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。
>
> どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。

Answer (score 0):

Double markdown block quote: `>>`

> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。
>
> どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番獰悪な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから別段恐しいとも思わなかった。
>
> > 夏目漱石, 1905, 吾輩は猫である

Answer (score 0):

Bolded with commas.

> 吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。
>
> どこで生れたかとんと見当がつかぬ。何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニャーニャー泣いていた事だけは記憶している。吾輩はここで始めて人間というものを見た。しかもあとで聞くとそれは書生という人間中で一番**獰悪**な種族であったそうだ。この書生というのは時々我々を捕えて煮て食うという話である。しかしその当時は何という考もなかったから**別段恐しい**とも思わなかった。
>
> **夏目漱石, 1905, 吾輩は猫である**

Comment: Problem here is if you need to highlight a part of the quote, bolding too much looks bad.