# Formatting Sandbox – Please test stuff here

Tags: discussion, formatting

Other sites have formatting sandboxes, so I figured, why not here?  After all, we've got lots of our own special markup.

If you need to try out any of the markup or formatting options on Japanese.SE to see what they look like, please make a post or leave a comment here! :-) That way you can get it right when you post it on the main site.

For more information about the special formatting options we have here on Japanese.SE, please see our meta question:

→　[How should I format my questions on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/1478)

You might also want to take a look at the sandbox on Meta.SE:

→　[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/215040)

Answer (score 2):

An old comment had a formatting problem due to the [double-slash IPA font support](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se/1291#1291) we added.  I'm testing a fix, placing a zero-width space between the pairs of slashes to keep it from parsing it that way.

EDIT: The workaround works!

Comment: **Original comment**: In my humble opinion, 迷惑 shows "trouble" or "annoyance" ("suffering" may be hinted but it's not the general meaning of it). // 迷惑の意味はない  -- The sentence infers some kind of "suffering". I think you've forgotten the negation in your translation. // Your translation of "多くは客観的な意味を表します" seems clunky 客観的 means objective (the writer doesn't tell his/her mind) not narrative (which is more about relating events the point of view used when relating events could be objective as well as subjective). // Besides that, I like your post and your use of references.

Comment: **Edited comment**: In my humble opinion, 迷惑 shows "trouble" or "annoyance" ("suffering" may be hinted but it's not the general meaning of it). /​/ 迷惑の意味はない  -- The sentence infers some kind of "suffering". I think you've forgotten the negation in your translation. /​/ Your translation of "多くは客観的な意味を表します" seems clunky 客観的 means objective (the writer doesn't tell his/her mind) not narrative (which is more about relating events the point of view used when relating events could be objective as well as subjective). /​/ Besides that, I like your post and your use of references.

Comment: //テスト// //ˈsneɪlboʊt//　//あいうえお日本語// //chocolate//

Answer (score 2):

> 1. 【ノーシン】　：「いえ、別に教会運営によるものではないのです」
> 2. 【アスタ】　　：「ん？　じゃあ、どうして？」
> 3. 【サイレント】：「ぶっちゃけ、解読された内容を読んだ教皇はショックを受けて、びびっています。単にへたれているだけですね」
> 4. 【ノーシン】　：「お恥ずかしながら、その通りです」
> 5. 【アスタ】　　：「相変わらずサイレントさん容赦ないな」
> 6. 【ノーシン】　：「あまりに衝撃的なので、まだ各国の王にもお話ししておりません……」
> 7. 【ラミアス】　：「では、なぜアスタにだけ話すのだ？」
> 8. 【サイレント】：「それは……アスタさんが蛇紋の総帥――　前教皇のセーデスと戦う決意をなさっているからです」
> 9. →【キャスリン】：「**そこまでのものなのか**……」

---

> **ノーシン**
> 　「いえ、別に教会運営によるものではないのです」
>
> **アスタ**
> 　「ん？　じゃあ、どうして？」
>
> **サイレント**
> 　「ぶっちゃけ、解読された内容を読んだ教皇はショックを受けて、びびっています。単にへたれているだけですね」
>
> **ノーシン**
> 　「お恥ずかしながら、その通りです」
>
> **アスタ**
> 　「相変わらずサイレントさん容赦ないな」
>
> **ノーシン**
> 　「あまりに衝撃的なので、まだ各国の王にもお話ししておりません……」
>
> **ラミアス**
> 　「では、なぜアスタにだけ話すのだ？」
>
> **サイレント**
> 　「それは……アスタさんが蛇紋の総帥――前教皇のセーデスと戦う決意をなさっているからです」
>
> **キャスリン**
> 　「**そこまでのものなのか**……」

---

```
1. 　【ノーシン】　「いえ、別に教会運営によるものではないのです」
2. 　【アスタ】　　「ん？　じゃあ、どうして？」
3. 　【サイレント】「ぶっちゃけ、解読された内容を読んだ教皇はショックを
     　　　　　　　　受けて、びびっています。単にへたれているだけですね」
4. 　【ノーシン】　「お恥ずかしながら、その通りです」
5. 　【アスタ】　　「相変わらずサイレントさん容赦ないな」
6. 　【ノーシン】　「あまりに衝撃的なので、まだ各国の王にもお話ししてお
   　　　　　　　　　りません……」
7. 　【ラミアス】　「では、なぜアスタにだけ話すのだ？」
8. 　【サイレント】「それは……アスタさんが蛇紋の総帥――前教皇のセーデス
   　　　　　　　　　と戦う決意をなさっているからです」
9. →【キャスリン】「そこまでのものなのか……」
```

Comment: Trying to get stuff to align, and observing the results on the computer and on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

㣺{したごころ} can be written [㣺]{したごころ}

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/severe-rendering-issue-in-some-fonts-what-happened)... Looks like bolding kanji breaks renderings. Let me test that out here.

「漢字を**太字**にすると、描画が**偉いことになる**」という*編集*を食らったのでテスト。

> 「漢字を**太字**にすると、描画が**偉いことになる**」という*編集*を食らったのでテスト。

- 「漢字を**太字**にすると、描画が**偉いことになる**」という*編集*を食らったのでテスト。

Answer (score 0):

So how do I format the following:

## 日本語

本は机の上です。

## English

The book is on the table.

## 日本語

At this point, I want the tabbed translation section ended and back to the answer; in other words, I want **this exact portion** of text shown in the question at all times, without having to write it twice (please edit this answer to check that I've written this twice).

## English

At this point, I want the tabbed translation section ended and back to the answer; in other words, I want **this exact portion** of text shown in the question at all times, without having to write it twice (please edit this answer to check that I've written this twice).